# Do we need an addition clause after Supposing [what if]?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I'll just quote from my vocabulary book:

> Note the use of **supposing** and **what if** (both usually found in
> spoken language) for possible situations in the future. **What if** is
> **more direct**.

What does **more direct** mean? I also want to know whether I should put an addition clause after the usage of **supposing**. For instance, here is an example:

> **Mick** : *Ethan's coming tomorrow. He'll help us.*
>
> **Alice** : ___ *he doesn't turn up*[1] - *what shall we do then*[2]?

In my opinion (according to my understanding) I simply can use **what if** that I don't have to add the second [2] clause. I mean, just using [1]:

> *What if he doesn't turn up?*

is enough. I think it's understandable. What about the word **supposing**? Do I have to add the second clause for the sake of clarity? Does-

> *Supposing he doesn't turn up?*

sound natural? I mean, in my view, it's more convenient and natural if I say:

> *Supposing he doesn't turn up - what shall we do then*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all four options sound natural to me:

> **Mick:** Ethan's coming tomorrow. He'll help us.
> **Alice:**
>
> 1. What if he doesn't turn up — what shall we do then?
> 2. Supposing he doesn't turn up — what shall we do then?
> 3. What if he doesn't turn up?
> 4. Supposing he doesn't turn up?

In the latter two cases the "what shall we do then?" is implied, and is understood to be the real question even if it is not said out loud.

Answer (score 1):

All four of your answers are grammatically correct and natural, and they have nearly the same meaning.

"What if" invites the other person to consider something as a real possibility.

"Supposing" invites the other person to consider something as a hypothetical situation.

This is what your book means when they say that "what if" is more direct.

So, in your example, "Supposing he doesn't show up?" sounds like something to imagine because it's interesting, but not because it's a real possibility that we have to prepare for.